# OAuth2 Bearer token used like API_KEY

Tags: oauth-2.0

We want to make simple authorization for server-server HTTPS communication (we control both servers) like classic API_KEY: client has hardcoded (in a config) a key which use in every request. Server check if the key is valid.

Our colleague has implemented it like OAuth2 Bearer token ([RFC6750](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc6750.txt))

`Authorization: Bearer client_key`

So the client has the `client_key` in the config, it's never refreshed. It works well, we have just a philosophical dispute in the company, if such "hardcoded" Bearer token is along with OAuth2 or not. (*Disclaimer*: I am not with any side of the dispute.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The OAuth 2.0 protocol basically defines an `access_token` - which is a token that is bound in time and permissions - and two protocol "legs":

1. how to obtain and access token
2. how to use/present an access token

You do not use access tokens (since your tokens are not bound in any way) and you've only "syntactically" implemented part 2. In fact you don't actually implement OAuth 2.0 in that case. You may present the `client_key` just as well in an HTTP Basic header or in a query parameter, it has nothing to do with OAuth 2.0 except that you're borrowing (arguably: abusing...) its header name and format.